# Angular 8 Input Material not styled

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

Currently the input field looks like this:

[image]

One of my components has the following HTML:

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="Favorite food" value="Sushi">
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <textarea matInput placeholder="Leave a comment"></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

My app.module.ts has the follwing:

[image]

Any reason why the input is not styled like in the [examples](https://material.angular.io/components/input/examples)?

[image]

Comment: did you included the material library with the `ng add @angular/material` command? it could be that you forgot to import the material theme if you had imported it by hand

Comment: i added the ng add @angular/material command before (indigo/pink) theme; nothing changed

Comment: Do you have  'FormsModule' or/and 'ReactiveFormsModule' also imported?

Comment: @PedroB.i added them now, but no change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to import Material Form Field Module in your NgModule.
Also it is required to add Material CSS in your `style.scss`

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

And in `app.module.ts` add `MatInputModule`

```
import {MatInputModule,MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material';

// ....
imports: [
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    ...
],
```

Refer to the docs: [Form-Field](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/api), and [Example](https://angular-avlgjh.stackblitz.io)

Comment: Do you have any online demo like on stackblitz ?

Comment: @rohan-humar not sure how to add ng add @angular/material to stackblitz

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please add Material CSS, and MatInputModule in your application.

Comment: The styles.css already contains @import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"; in the image in the post MatInputModule,MatFormFieldModule are included :) I will try to set up a stackblitz

Comment: Please see the demo on https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-avlgjh

Comment: So I managed to get it working on https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uefxm9 added @import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css'; in styles then installed the dependencies using npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk

npm install --save @angular/animations      ------ still not working on localhost : )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204119/discussion-between-rohan-kumar-and-naffets).

Comment: I managed to get it to work @rohan-kumar; apparently there were multiples modules files.

Comment: Ok great; (thumbs-up)